# If $\| \alpha(s) \| \leq \| \alpha(s_0) \| = R$, then the curvature $k(s_0)$ is greater than $1/R$

Tags: differential-geometry

This question is in Ted Shifrin's A first course in curves and surfaces, page 18, exercise 7:

> Suppose $\alpha$ is an arclength-parametrized space curve with the property that $\| \alpha(s) \| \leq \| \alpha(s_0) \| = R$ for  all $s$ sufficiently close to $s_0$ . Prove that $k(s_0) \geq 1/R$. (Hint: Consider the function $f(s)=\| \alpha(s)\|^2$. What do you know about $f''(s_0)$?)

Here's what I have tried:

$$f(s) = \| \alpha(s)\|^2 =  \langle \alpha(s), \alpha(s) \rangle \implies f'(s) = 2 \langle T(s), \alpha(s) \rangle $$

And using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality :

$$f'(s_0) = 2 \langle T(s_0), \alpha(s_0) \rangle \leq 2 \|T(s_0)\|\|\alpha(s_0)\|=2R \implies \langle T(s_0), \alpha(s_0) \rangle \leq R$$

Now we find $f''(s)$:

$$f''(s) = 2 \langle k(s)N(s), \alpha(s) \rangle  + 2 (\langle T(s), \langle T(s \rangle )=  2 k(s) \langle N(s), \alpha(s) \rangle  + 2$$

And because $s_0$ is maximum of $\| \alpha(s)\|$:

$$2 k(s_0) \langle N(s_0), \alpha(s_0) \rangle  + 2 \leq 0 \implies -1/k(s_0) \geq \langle N(s_0), \alpha(s_0) \rangle$$

I don't know how to continue from here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, what *is* $f'(s_0)$, precisely? No inequalities here. You should be thinking about Cauchy-Schwarz in the analysis of the second derivative. Several warnings: First, $s_0$ is a *maximum*, not a minimum; but $f''(s_0)\le 0$  (not strict inequality). Second, think about the sign of $\langle N(s_0),\alpha(s_0)\rangle$. Last, don't divide by $k(s_0)$ if you want to solve for $k(s_0)$ :)

Comment: Incomplete "hint answers" like this do not help anyone who wants the actual answer. As someone with a very poor understanding of differential geometry, this answer is useless to me. Stack Exchange is about curating knowledge, not about helping the person who asked the question and them alone.

Comment: @forest  We'll have to agree to disagree. Witness the huge number of duplicates and near duplicates.

Comment: That is a thought-terminating cliché. Referring to duplicates may be valid (I have not seen any), but does not change my opinion that _this_ answer to _this_ question is incomplete.

Comment: @forest if you have a very poor understanding of differential geometry, then you should start with easier problems. SE is not an encyclopedia, it is not a list of solved questions that your textbook is "missing." Curating knowledge in mathematics involves providing insight, and Professor Shifrin does this by offering a thought process that would lead OP to the answer. That is probably how you curate knowledge. Have you taught a class? Do you have a degree in math education? Have you taught any classes? Why would you claim to know more about curating knowledge  than a lifelong professor. Sheesh

Comment: @TedShifrin +1 by the way. Sorry for the rant on what I thought was a nice answer, that helped me answer the question (with some work), which I stumbled upon.

Comment: @AndresMejia, thanks for your support in these contentious times. :) If you haven't already done so, check out my text. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin I definitely will, I'm excited to take a first course in differential geometry next semester. I have on the other hand used your videos to learn about differential forms. Those were great! thanks for sharing your knowledge :)

Comment: @Andres Great. Keep me posted!!

Comment: @AndresMejia When did I say anything about knowing more about curating knowledge than a professor? I said that Stack Exchange is supposed to be a collection of information. It explicitly compares itself to Wikipedia (to differentiate itself from a forum). If you want half-completed answers that you have to finish yourself, that's what a textbook is for. If you have a question and want an answer, that's what SE is for.

Answer (score 24):

This question is a classic from curve and surface geometry.  Good to run into it here, like an old friend one hasn't see in awhile.

These things being said:

We note the hypothesis that

$\Vert \alpha(s) \Vert \le \Vert \alpha(s_0) \Vert \tag 1$

essentially tells us that $s_0$ is a *local maximum* of the function $\Vert \alpha(s_0) \Vert$; since the real function $w \to w^2$ is strictly monotonically increasing for $w \ge 0$, $s_0$ will also be a local maximum for $\Vert \alpha(s) \Vert^2$; we shall work with this function *in lieu* of $\Vert \alpha(s) \Vert$.

We set

$f(s) = \Vert \alpha(s) \Vert^2 = \langle \alpha(s), \alpha(s) \rangle; \tag 2$

then

$f'(s) = 2\langle \alpha'(s), \alpha(s) \rangle = 2\langle T(s),  \alpha(s) \rangle, \tag 3$

where

$T(s) =\alpha'(s) \tag 4$

is the *unit tangent vector field* to the curve $\alpha(s)$; we further have

$f''(s) = 2\langle T'(s), \alpha(s) \rangle + 2\langle T(s), T(s) \rangle; \tag{5}$

we may take this equation a step further by recalling that $T(s)$ is a unit vector and

$T'(s) = \kappa(s) N(s), \tag 6$

where $N(s)$ is the *unit normal field* to, and $\kappa(s) > 0$ is the *curvature* of, $\alpha(s)$.  Thus,

$f''(s) = 2\kappa(s) \langle N(s), \alpha(s) \rangle + 2; \tag 7$

since $s_0$ is a local maximum of $f(s)$, we must have

$f''(s) \le 0; \tag 8$

thus,

$\kappa(s_0) \langle N(s_0), \alpha(s_0) \rangle + 1 \le 0, \tag 9$

or

$\kappa(s_0)\langle N(s_0), \alpha(s_0) \rangle \le -1; \tag{10}$

taking absolute values of both sides, we find

$\kappa(s_0)\vert \langle N(s_0), \alpha(s_0) \rangle \vert \ge 1; \tag{11}$

by Cauchy-Schwarz,

$\vert \langle N(s_0), \alpha(s_0) \rangle \vert \le \Vert N(s_0) \Vert \Vert \alpha(s_0) \Vert = \Vert \alpha(s_0) \Vert \tag{12}$

since

$\Vert N(s_0) \Vert = 1; \tag{13}$

combining (11) and (12), we obtain

$\kappa(s_0) R \ge 1, \tag{14}$

whence

$\kappa(s_0) \ge \dfrac{1}{R}. \tag{15}$

Comment: Robert: Please don't ruin my textbook by posting complete solutions to the homeworks. You realize you're likely doing lots of students' homework this way. (This person is asking for guidance, not a professional solution.)

Comment: @TedShifrin: with all due respect, and I *do* admire your book and your work,  have I done so before?  If so, can you cite links to such answers?  Also, most of my post re-iterated what the OP already had stated; in light of that, I merely added a few notes to the end of his attempt.  "Ruin my textbook", which I said I admired, seems pretty strong.  Best Regards.

Comment: For those of us who assign graded homework (and, in particular, this problem), it renders it far too easy for students not to learn and just turn in your work as their own. This is, admittedly, what I detest about this site. When a student asks for a hint, suggestion, or guidance, why must people (yes, you, included) indulge themselves by writing a polished, complete solution? (This I have witnessed numerous times.) You did not merely add a few notes ...

Comment: @TedShifrin:  It seems to me a legitimate question as to how is myself or any other user of this site to know if the poster is taking a class using your book or just reading it?  I don't think I'm wrong in asserting that many questions posted on this site occur in textbooks, whether they are quoted as such or not.  Also, if you look carefully at the last line in the question, you will see that the poster was right on top of the answer, he just didn't get how to use Cauchy-Schwarz in this context.  I did, and so posted.  By the way, am I wrong in assuming that you downvoted my answer?

Comment: Dear all: there is now a [meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29122/i-dont-know-how-to-proceed-in-this-situation) regarding this - FYI.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I am very much against cheating, including gaining unfair advantage over other students. However, I also think that you should not impose on others concerning questions taken from your textbook unless it is according to the site guidelines. We do already have a contest policy for publicly available contests, but it is already nearly impossible to enforce, as you surely know. While you could ask people here nicely to not provide full polished solutions, they are free to do otherwise within site guidelines, and that in no way "ruins your textbook".

Comment: You too are free to not give textbook problems as **graded** homework. With the rise of the internet (and Yahoo Answers being a much worse culprit than Math SE), the only way to prevent student cheating is to use proctored assessment. Attempting to impose rules on online communities would be like a Whack-A-Mole game that never actually works. Maybe sad, but that's the way it is...

Comment: @TedShifrin Respectfully, this answer at most ruins your graded homework, if anything, not your book. Secondly, students that receive graded homework have hundreds of ways to cheat. They can, for example, copy the solutions from each other. They can pay someone to do it (I have seen this happen several times unfortunately). A  well written answer on Math.SE should be the least of your concerns. Congratulations on giving graded homework assignments, that is I great thing in my opinion, but respectfully I think your reaction doesn't make sense.